# change php version in phpinfo()

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to change my php version in `phpinfo`

when i type `php -v` in console, i get this

```
PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 17 2022 16:48:09) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

but in my phpinfo is shows as `PHP Version 8.0.19`

i tried `sudo update-alternatives --config php` in my command prompt and got this

```
  Selection    Path                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/php.default   100       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php.default   100       manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/php8.0        80        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php8.1        81        manual mode
```

i selected 3, and restarted apache. but it still shows as `PHP Version 8.0.19`

I also tried the steps here to upgrade php for apache

https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-or-upgrade-php-8-1-on-ubuntu-20-04/

any ideas what i'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Php-fpm is the version running on the Apache and php-cli is for the version in console. Read over this link, should cover both https://iknowthatnow.com/2021/05/07/change-php-version-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: @MisterG13 i already did `sudo a2dismod php8.0` and `sudo a2enmod php8.1` and restarted apache. still no luck

Answer (score 2):

## To change php version in Apache2 phpinfo() (Switch between php version)

Solution:
I have done this solution by few steps, you can try.
suppose i am trying to change the active version php8.1 to php7.4:

Steps1: First stop/disable the active version

```
sudo a2dismod php8.1
systemctl restart apache2
```

Steps2: First start/enable the targeted version

```
sudo a2enmod php7.4
```

Steps3: Restart apache2

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

OR

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Step4: Set manually the location:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.4
```

Or
You can also try your below method

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo update-alternatives --config phar
sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar
```

Step6:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Now Solved, brows

> phpinfo

Example:
create a page named phpinfo.php into the local server.

```
<?php 

echo phpinfo();

?>
```

http://localhost/phpinfo.php